# wildcard brings error in wxPython FileDialog

Tags: python, file, dialog, wxpython

I am trying to build an example from book "wxPython in Action" page 270.

Here is the code:

```
import wx
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    wildcard = "Python source(*.py)|*.py|"\"Compiled Python(*.pyc)|*.pyc|"\"All files(*.*)|*.*"

    dlg = wx.FileDialog(None, "Choose input file", os.getcwd(), "", wildcard, wx.OPEN)

    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        print dlg.GetPath()

    dlg.Destroy()
```

I saved it as .py source file, and run it in IDLE. But it gives me following error:

> There's an error in your program: unexpected character after line
>   comtinuation character

May I know why this example doesn't work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change

```
wildcard = "Python source(*.py)|*.py|"\"Compiled Python(*.pyc)|*.pyc|"\"All files(*.*)|*.*"
```

to

```
wildcard = "Python source(*.py)|*.py|Compiled Python(*.pyc)|*.pyc|All files(*.*)|*.*"
```

Comment: isn't it obvious? The escape character is in the outside of a string. You don't even need one here at all

Comment: No. Please state it in the answer. Point out the error and then tell the fix. It's good standard to do that.

Comment: with the update of wxPython I'm encountering similar situation... but why? PS: for example this look doesn't work `wildcard_f  = "Fasta File (*.fasta)|*.fasta|Amino Acids Fasta File(*.faa)|*.faa|"`